# how to call over values from one function to another using GUIDE?

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-guide, handles

So I try to use handles to call over a created array from a callback function (`select_cmp_Callback`), shown below) to a create function (bot_igntmassflux_1_CreateFcn).
But apparently all that failed and it keep saying `Undefined function or variable "cmp_list".`

thanks in advance!

```
% --- Executes on button press in select_cmp.
function select_cmp_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.cmp',...
    'Component Files (*.cmp)';'*.txt', 'Text Files (*.txt)';...
    '*.*','All Files (*.*)'},'Select the Components File'); %add default path
if isequal(FileName,0)
    disp('User selected Cancel')
else
    disp(['User selected ', fullfile(PathName, FileName)])
    copyfile(fullfile(PathName, FileName));
    fdd = fopen(FileName);
    file_strings = textscan(fdd, '%s', 'Delimiter', ':');
    fclose(fdd);
    delete(FileName);
    file_strings_sz=size(file_strings{1}); %size of file_strings (number of rows)
    file_strings_ix=0;
    cmp_ix=0;
    while file_strings_ix < file_strings_sz(1,1)
        file_strings_ix = file_strings_ix+1;
        if strcmp(file_strings{1}{file_strings_ix},'COMPONENT')
            file_strings_ix = file_strings_ix+1;
            cmp_ix=(cmp_ix)+1;
            cmp_list{cmp_ix,1} = cellstr(file_strings{1}{file_strings_ix}); 
            file_strings_ix = file_strings_ix+1;
        end
    end
end

disp(cmp_list);

handles.cmp_list = cmp_list;


function bot_igntmassflux_1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

cmp_list = handles.cmp_list;

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end

set(hObject,'String',cmp_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

The struct `handles` is a GUI data object. If you change it, and want other functions to access the updated struct, you have to store it as the new GUI data by using the `guidata` function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).
Use the following command in the end of any GUI function if you update `handles`:

```
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: I am sorry but I tried looking at that and doing it myself but still does not make much sense... Do you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: First, you should add the command at the last line of `select_cmp_Callback`.  In any case, I believe that `bot_igntmassflux_1_CreateFcn` is called when the GUI is opened so I don't quite understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: Oh soo i am trying to add options that cmp_list has in the createfcn when it is selected. But i am still going through the same error